# What do you call it when you have two subnets and find the a common SUPERsubnet that can be used to access both of them?4

Tags: networking, cisco, router, subnet

I have a Networking test in about 6 hours and I lost my notes on the subject matter and can't recall what the acronym was! Here's the problem case:

Given the address 150.20.0.0/27 find the following subnets and appropriate 'subsubnets' (what's that called as well).

The graphic then goes on to show a diagram of many routers all connected and some routers have a switch connected with a number like 6000h meaning 6000 hosts. My task is to find the SUBsubnet that is needed to accomodate the ammount of hosts without wasting any IP addresses.

The thing I remember is that SUBsubnets have a different subnet mask '/28, /30' than the base father mask.

There is also the matter of connectivity, I have to make sure the entire network can ping whereever. They gave a class on the subject, but again, I can't remember the acronym. I think it was CDLRP or something like that. We're using Cisco's Packet Tracer, so any commands related to this would be great. Basically it's like this:

[image]

I hope all of this is making sense to you guys. Any help would be appreciated and some links to tutorials so I can brush up on them before the test.

Comment: They're not called subsubnets, they're called subnets. 150.20.0.0/27 is not considered a subnet, it's considered a network (it actually is a subnet of a larger network but from your perspective consider it a network, not a subnet). Any networks that you split off from the 150.20.0.0/27 network are called subnets, because they are subnets of the 150.20.0.0/27 network.

Comment: Also, it's not called a supersubnet, it's called a supernet. You can also refer to it as supernetting, route aggregation, or route summarization.

Comment: There's no sub-subnet; they're all just subnets. If you have a /24 subnet; you can divide that into several smaller subnets. I think the term supernet is leftover from the Classed IPs of yore; I wouldn't use it anymore, as others have said, it's a network or a subnet.

Comment: Can you guys suggest a good tutorial for learning about supernetting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CIDR ?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR

Comment: Yeah I think that's the answer to the a part of my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's called CIDR and actually it means that you don't have classes in your network. 
Which can be translated as ... you can use any submask you want.

Answer (score 0):

Route summarization != CIDR. In fact a classful network *is* a summarization of its subnets.